# About the closure of the subset of n'th roots of the identity matrix.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, general-linear-group

I'm working with the square roots of the identity matrix and it seems that the only thing that prevents this subset of the general linear group from being a subgroup is closure. Since the identity itself is in this subset and every element is it's own inverse, I wonder how the smallest subgroup of the general linear group that contains this subset looks like and how to generalize this with n'th roots instead of just square roots.

(New guy over here, sorry if I made any mistakes regarding the rules for asking and such)

Edit: I'm working over the complex numbers, but I guess it could be over any field.

Comment: Note that this subgroup must be normal, since the generating set is closed under conjugation. "The" general linear group (over most fields, say) has very few normal subgroups. Typically, they are either contained in the center (and consist of scalar matrices), or contain the special linear group. In this case, you have matrices that are not scalar (like some permutation matrices), so it must contain the special linear group. By the first isomorphism theorem, it's either the special linear group or the group of matrices with determinant $\pm 1$. (Assuming we are working over a field.)

Comment: In fact, it is quite easy to find a matrix of determinant $-1$ with this property, such as a diagonal matrix with 1 on the diagonal except one $-1$. So the group  you are interested in will consist exactly of all matrices with determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: @verret: I would suggest to post your answer in the "answer" box and not in the "comment" box.

Comment: Very helpful @verret, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "the" general linear group but, in general, the answers to such questions can depend on the dimension or the field you are working over. (Although not much in this case.)

The subgroup you are considering is clearly a normal subgroup of the general linear group, as the generating set is closed under conjugation. (In fact, it is clearly a characteristic subgroup.)

In most cases, "the" general linear groups has very few normal subgroups. They are either "small" and contained in the center (and consist of scalar matrices), or "large" and contain the special linear group.

(There are some exceptions to this statement, for example $GL(2,3)$.)

Now, the subgroup you are considering clearly has non-scalar matrices (like some permutation matrices of order $2$), so it must contain the special linear group. In particular, it is completely determined by the set of determinants of matrices represented. If we are working over a field, a matrix of order $2$ must have determinant $\pm 1$. You can take a matrix with $1$ on the diagonal, except one $-1$, to show that you do have some matrices of determinant $-1$. So the group is exactly the set of matrices of determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I have to work out the details to attempt to prove these claims, but it seems pretty straightforward and intuitive having this information at hand. Thanks again, and have a nice week!

Comment: You might then want to accept the answer.